# NuxtJs generate for dynamic websites?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm creating a simple demo app with NuxtJs. The homepage shows static content that is not changed very often. There is another route for showing a list of users: `/users`. And one for showing user's details: `/user/id`.

Now my question is what's the difference between `nuxt generate` and `nuxt build`?  which one should I use?

I think `nuxt generate` page will not render dynamic routes like `users` and `user/id`, Am I right?  If I am right, then `generate` command will generate a pre-rendered HTML for homepage only. So using `generate` is always better than using `build` right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `universal` mode, `nuxt generate` is for static site generation. `nuxt build` is for [SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/) site.

> In 2.13.0, `Nuxt` introduced a `target: static` feature, make sure to
> check [it](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static).

A static site has the best performance, and it is easy to deploy on nginx or other services, like `Netlify`.

By default, `nuxt generate` only render your static home page and `/users` page, not the dynamic `/user/:id` route.

But you can [config](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/) nuxt to help you generate the dynamic routes.

1. If you have a fixed set of users, you can use functions to [generate the routes](https://vueschool.io/lessons/how-to-deploy-nuxtjs-to-netlify?friend=nuxt).
2. If the users data is constantly in change, you can [config](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#fallback) nuxt to fallback to SPA on the dynamic routes. But you can't get any benefit for SEO on the dynamic routes.

For SPA fallback, in the [generate config](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/), define a custom page for SPA fallback:

```
export default {
  generate: {
    fallback: "custom_sap_fallbackpage.html"
  }
}
```

Config the fallback page for unknow route in your deployment, for example, in Nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /custom_sap_fallbackpage.html;
}
```

`nuxt build` will build you a SSR site. The html is rendered on the server and sent to the client. It add some work load on the server and maybe is not that easy to deploy, but the main gain is the SEO. And to some users with low end devices or slow internet connection, maybe your site will perform better than depolying in SPA mode.

Basically, you need to consider:

1. The website's content is static or constantly changing?

`nuxt generate` for static. `nuxt generate` or `nuxt build` or `spa` mode for sites with dynamic routes.

2. Do you need SEO?

SPA wouldn't get any SEO.

3. How you deploy the site?

For static hosting service, only `nuxt generate` or `spa` mode will work.

4. your website is heavy with js code, and you want best performance for user with slow internet and slow devices. Or SEO is important for your site with a lot of dynamic content.

SSR is for you, use `nuxt build`.

Comment: The generate fallback tip and nginx config totally did it for me, thanks a lot @Franci

Comment: Glad to help. : )

Answer (score 2):

There are three different deployment and generation options in Nuxt.

**Universal Mode**

---

In this mode you build your project and then you ship it to a node.js server, the first view is always rendered dynamically on the server and then turns into SPA, and works in the client. That's great for SEO, and for consuming API's but you cannot upload it to any hosting, for example on a shared VPS.

So - Node.js Host is required here.

**SPA**

---

Well basically how Vue.js works by default, virtually **no SEO at all**, you can upload it on a shared VPS hosting, because it's just an index.html and build.js file and it's working entirely on the client-side (in the browser).

We can go for a static hosting here.

**Static App**

---

This is where Nuxt.js shines, because this mode will generate an index.html file and the corresponding js/css assets for each route you have in the dist folder, and you can then just take those numerous files, and upload them to any hosting, you don't need a server here, because your first views are already pre-rendered, unlike Universal where the node server should pre-render the first view. So you get SSR here, and your main concert as far as I understand is if you get SPA too, and that's the best part as in Universal mode, after the first request the app continues in SPA mode, how great is that eh?

Anyways there are some things you should take into consideration, that if you want to generate index.html for dynamic content you need to make something that's kinda a mood killer. You need to add this to `nuxt-config.js`

```
generate: {
    routes: () => {
      return [
        '/posts/1'
      ]
    }    
  }
```

You can also use axios to make http request and return array here. Or even export default array from a file and include it here, where you combine all your dynamic routes. It's a one time job, but if you add new crud in your backend, that would add up 1 more request to run on executing nuxt generate that should be described in nuxt-config.

So that's the reason I would prefer to pay more for a server, but to host a Universal App, instead static generated, because that's the part that doesn't make it really great for consuming API's in my personal opinion, but it is a great future anyways.

Answer (score -1):

when you website update data often you don't need to use build by using `npm generate` your website static, load fast and SEO friendly for search engine and more secure and if your project has data NuxtJS download all data from database and change data to .json file statically.

if your website load data from the database you must use `npm build` to load data dynamically from database. use mode "spa" for a single page without client-side rendering or "universal" in `nuxt.config.js` for client-side rendering.

for dynamic routing use `npm build` for change route parameters from the database.